# Facebook Open Graph and authentification

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook Open Graph to tell stories about my users following other users. I created a custom action called "trusts".

I would like the URL attached to the followed user to be that user's URL in the site, i.e.:
myapp/users/64

HOwever when I implement Open Graph it returns an error when it scrapes the URL.

The reason is of course that the user page is behind a login protocol and when the scraper tries to hit it, it redirects to the login page.

I built a custom page that does not redirect, but guess what? the url line (see below) causes Facebook to try out the URL anyways and so I am facing the same problem.

Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

the object:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# kweekwegg: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/kweekwegg#"
>  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<%= Facebook::APP_ID %>" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="kweekwegg:user" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="<%= Facebook::SITE_URL%>users/<%= params[:facebook_user] %>" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Ange" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"/>
```

the action:

```
function postTrust(user_id){
    alert("<%= Facebook::SITE_URL %>user_scrape?facebook_user="+user_id);
    FB.api(
  'me/kweekwegg:trust',
  'post',
  {
    user: "<%= Facebook::SITE_URL %>user_scrape?facebook_user="+user_id
    //user: "http://samples.ogp.me/371640646273751"
  },
  function(response) {
    alert(response.id);
  }
);
}
```

And finally remember that I create a custom page that  does not require identification, just takes the user ID as a param from the postTrust function - and yet FB seems to still be pinging that URL and so getting an error.

Comment: It does not make much sense to use content for the _Open_ Graph that is hidden behind a user login. Users that don’t even have an account with your site might see that content on Facebook as well, and when they follow a link, they will be prompted to login – bad user experience. If you still want to do it anyway, make an exception from this automatic redirecting for FB’s scraper based on its user agent.

Comment: @CBroe you were right and I fixed the problem based on your tip - passing a param to direct the user to his target page. I just render the login page if the user is not logged in, so the params from the link to the page are not lost in the redirect.